# Is it because $_GET is global or the form submitting to itself or else?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to understand one simple thing in PHP form handling.I am new to it and I have a sample code:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="">
   Item Name:<input type="text" name="itmName" id="itmName"/><br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" name="sbmit" value="Add Record"/>
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_GET['m']))
 {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$_GET['m'].'");</script>';  
 }
 if(isset($_POST['sbmit']))
 {
  header("location:1.php?m=10");
 }
?>
```

Irrespective of what data I send to the server, my focus is on the  `if(isset($_GET['m']))` part of the code. Everytime I submit the form, the 'if' is always evaluated to true and as a result the alert box appears.Is it because $_GET is holding the previous value set by `header("location:1.php?m=10");` or is it because the form is submitting to itself or else?Googling didn't provide much help. I need better understanding over this.With Thanks

Comment: `$_GET` will contain any query string data appended to the URL. If the URL you're accessing has `?m=10` on the end of it, `$_GET['m']` will be 10.

Comment: if you use post in from why you want to cacth GET? and on the other side where is `m` declared in your form?

Comment: Use your development tools, and see what happens in network.

Comment: m is declared in header("location:1.php?m=10");

Comment: why someone is negative voting without telling the true answer

Comment: The logic on handling GET/POST actions should be before the HTML output, or you will never be able to execute `header()` call. Why the redirection anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not specifying an action, it is going to get defaulted to the current pages url, in this case "1.php?m=10" (if that is what it was as you say).  Even though the form is getting submitted via POST, the query string is still passed and still accessible.

To prevent it from being set, all you need to do is specific your form action

Comment: My point is that: the server processes and gives the output to the client(browser). When I submit the form it sends to the server(the php script) and in the script how "if(isset($_GET['m']))" is evaluated even the variable m is set in the following block "if(isset($_POST['sbmit']))" as shown in the code

Comment: $_GET['m'] is set based on the URL of the file you are executing, regardless of whether that URL was accessed by posting a form, or simply navigating to it in your browser.  Basically, if you were to navigate to just http://yoursite.com/1.php. The first time you submit the form it shouldn't show up, but your url will now be http://yoursite.com/1.php?m=10.  The url your form submits to will now also be that url, so every time you submit the form after the first time it will always display the alert

Answer (score 0):

1°) when you submit your form, the post method send "itmName" and "sbmit" to the same page (because you didn't write anything in "action=").

2°) if the page received the post var 'sbmit', and i does, you ask to the server to redirect the page to the same page (i guess) with a get variable (m=10)

3°) you ordered your page to send an alert if it recieves something in the 'm' get variable.

So in only one shot, your sever does thoses 3 steps. That's why every time the alert is sent.

Comment: Hitting the submit button is a client side event. After sending the form data, the server process it. Here I want to know how if(isset($_GET['m'])) is evaluated in the server (i.e. evaluates to true) even though the following block only defines the variable 'm' as shown in the sample code. If I alter : 'header' first then comes 'if' then I think it be easier to understand as program flow is sequential.

Comment: You are right, the form is client side. When the submit button is cliked, the post datas are send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the form is client side.
When the submit button is cliked, the post datas are send to the server. Now in server side, the first thing the server see is "if(isset($_POST['sbmit']))" which orders a redirection but in php not in javascript, so we stay server side with the load of a new page that first need to be interpreted by the server because it contains a get variable.
This Get variable is detected by the server and automatically is turning "if(isset($_GET['m']))" on true. Now it writes the javascript tag that will be interpreted client side with the launch of the alert.